# Add an additional "hybrid" vCenter to a Datacenter

Tags: powershell, vmware, vcenter

vFriends.

I have a very specific question to make:

I have a Datacenter with 4 clusters, formed by 14 big hosts and almost 500 VMs. So many VMs showed the need to collect info from them. I have a tool that collects the info through several powershell scripts by myself that connects to the VIServer. Here is an example:

> add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core Connect-VIServer
>
> vCenterServer.mydomain.com -wa 0    Get-Stat -Realtime -MaxSamples 1
>
> -Stat cpu.latency.average -Entity (Get-VMHost * | Get-VM * | Where-Object {$_.PowerState –eq "PoweredOn"}) | Select-Object
>
> Entity,MetricId,Value | format-table

This one gets the last latency average read of all VMs. There are many others.

It has always worked like a charm, and I have more than 6 months of history and a good source for new investments and managerial decision making.

Until the VCB back up tool started to use a similar way to get info to perform back ups. When my tool is running, the back up never starts. I tried to install the PowerCLI in another server and try to collect from there, but it turned out to be painfully slow to retrieve the data (yes, I disabled the certificate check too) averaged in 5 minutes, compared to the 30sec from inside the vCenter.

OBS: vRealize doesn't give me the info I need. VMTurbo does, but it's too expensive to be bought by now.

Then, I have 3 alternatives that I thought of:

Use the other server and lose 450% of the current data sampling
Ask the BackUp analyst to stop my scripts to perform the back up everytime (causing another big gap in the collected data)
Install another vCenter server in order to run my scripts OR have the back up tool connect to it.

I don't actually want a vCenter to operate in the linked mode feature. I just want another vCenter for those listed purposes, just like an additional Active Directory server in a forest.

1. Is that possible?
2. Am I missing another good alternative?
3. How do I configure it?
4. Will a Plataform Services Controller server do the trick?

Thanks,

- Dave

Comment: Guess no one knows :(